# Running cgminer in the cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to run an Amazon instance AMI: ami-b93013d0. The name would have you think that it has cgminer on it. But I can only find minerd. Does anyone know how I can find cgminer on this AMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find / -name cgminer` to find the executable, assuming it's there.

Also, CGMiner only runs against CPUs (and certain other dedicated hardware, which Amazon doesn't have), AMD/ATI cores work the best by 10x. Minerd is an ancient program, which you should most definitely not be using anymore. If you need to run against a CPU, then you'll want a copy of `pool-cpuminer`.

I should warn you, no matter what coin you intend to mine, CPU mining costs more in electricity than you'll ever get out of it. Running a CPU miner against anything Amazon has will likely result in the same situation, even running 3-4+ year old AMD/ATI cards usually costs more in electricity than you'll get out of it. Mining is a sport for the dedicated, I'd be happy to walk you through the process, but unless you're ready for some dedication and minimal financial investment be ready to just burn money.

Finally, Server Fault is for Professional System Administration topics only. [Bitcoin.StackExchange.com](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) is a site where you can ask crypto-curreny questions (alt-coin questions are accepted there too, as they're almost all based on the Bitcoin protocol, if now the PoW Algorithm) .